# rpm unistall package error in linux

Tags: shell, rpm

I want to uninstall/remove/erase `sshpass` package from my linux.

I use the following command line

`rpm -e sshpass`

However, I get the following error: `error: package sshpass is not installed`
But `sshpass` IS indeed installed.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like (a) `sshpass` isn't installed via rpm, or (b) it's part of another package.

`rpm -qa | grep ssh` should show any ssh-related packages you have installed.

`rpm -q --whatprovides /path/to/sshpass` will tell you if another package is where it came from.

That executable is not on my Fedora 19 or CentOS 5 box, so I can't tell you which is the case.